# EF4 CTP5 self-referencing hierarchical entity mapping

Tags: hierarchical-data, ef4-code-only

Okay, this should be really easy, but I've been tearing my hair out.  Here's my POCO (which has to do with machine parts, so a part can be contained within a parent part):

```
public class Part
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Part ParentPart { get; set; }
}
```

When the database table is created, the column names are "ID", "Name", and "PartID".  How do I change the name of that last column to "ParentPartID"?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want to rename the foreign key in an *Independent Association* and this is the fluent API code that will do it:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Part>()
                .HasOptional(p => p.ParentPart)
                .WithMany()
                .IsIndependent()
                .Map(m => m.MapKey(p => p.ID, "ParentPartID"));
}
```

However, due to a bug in CTP5, this code throw as exception in *self referencing associations* (which is your association type). The workaround would be to change your association to a *Foreign Key Association* as follows:

```
public class Part
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }                
    public int ParentPartID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentPartID")]
    public Part ParentPart { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: .. and due to another bug in CTP5, this attribute will be ignored, along with the ParentPart property name ;-)