# EF Codefirst How to create a key from multiple columns with DataAnnotations

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am trying to get a composite key declared in a class with Attributes and DataAnnotation.

```
[Key]
[Column(Order=1)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }

[Key]
[Column(Order=2)]
public int Nr { get; set; }
```

does not seem to get this going. 
All I could find up to now was some fluent option, but I'd like to do this with annotations only.

To clarify: 
I am searching for a DataAnnotation way to create a table with a primary key consisting of 2 fields Id and Nr...

Thanks for your help
   Andreas

Answer (score 10):

You can easily do this as follows using Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourClass>().HasKey(obj => new {obj.Id,obj.Nr});
```

Also, you can create separate class that inherit from `EntityTypeConfiguration` and add this line in its constructor:

```
public class <*Name*>Mapping:EntityTypeConfiguration<*Name*> 

      public <*Name*>Mapping(){
             this.HasKey(obj => new {obj.Id,obj.Nr});
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question last week but was looking for the fluent syntax.  The answer provided by Morteza (search for more of his answers regarding anything ef/CTP5- he is awesome) also gives the syntax for using data annotations.

Here is the [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811194/what-is-the-syntax-for-self-referencing-foreign-keys-in-ef-code-first)  Hope this helps.

Comment: That is not what I am searching for. :-(