# Mapping for self referencing entity in EF Code First 

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, ef-code-first, relational-database

In my database I have a table Category, with columns Id, CategoryName, ParentCategoryId, where ParentCategoryId has a constraint on Category.Id.

I'm using entity framework code first, where the entity looks like:

```
public class Category
{
   public long Id { get; private set; }
   public string CategoryName { get; private set; }
   public long? ParentCategoryId { get; private set; }
   public Category ParentCategory { get; private set; }       
   public virtual ICollection<Category> SubCategories { get; private set; }
}
```

If I try to run a query against this, I get the exception:

```
 The relationship 'ComplaintModel.FK_Complaint_Category' was not loaded because the type 'ComplaintModel.Category' is not available.\r\nThe following information may be useful in resolving the previous error:\r\nThe required property 'Category1' does not exist on the type 'EC.Complaint.Services.Command.Domain.Entities.Category'.\r\n\r\n"}    System.Exception {System.Data.MetadataException}
```

So it seems it needs navigation properties, if I add these:

```
 public ICollection<Category> Category1 { get; private set; }
 public long? Category2Id { get; private set; }
 public Category Category2 { get; private set; }
```

the query works.

But of course, I don't want the Category1 and Category2 properties, I want ParentCategory and SubCategories properties being used.

How can I tell code first to use the correct navigation properties?

Comment: Very similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4812413/97803

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your POCO class should look like this ...

```
public class Category
{
   public long Id { get; private set; }
   public string CategoryName { get; private set; }
   public long? ParentCategoryId { get; private set; }
   public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; private set; }       
   public virtual ICollection<Category> SubCategories { get; private set; }
}

public class CategoryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public CategoryConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        this.HasMany(category => category.SubCategories)
            .WithOptional(category => category.ParentCategoryId)
            .HasForeignKey(course => course.UserId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: As you suggested I tried 'modelBuilder.Entity<Domain.Entities.Category>().HasMany(category => category.SubCategories).WithRequired(category => category.ParentCategory).HasForeignKey(category => category.Id).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);' and indeed, that also works. I like your approach better, it's strongly typed! Thanks!

Comment: or maybe it should be WithOptional instead of WithRequired...?

Comment: @Lud, Yes, sorry it should be WithOptional.

Comment: Interesting, was having trouble putting it the other way around. e.g. .HasOptional(x=> x.Parent).WithMany(c=>c.Children) , which didn't give desired results , however this works thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Entity Framework 6 handles this. You have to just ensure [Key] annotation is used to identify primary key. Not sure if it works with virtual keyword or not.

```
 public class Category
{
   [Key]
   public long Id { get; private set; }
   public string CategoryName { get; private set; }
   public long? ParentCategoryId { get; private set; }
   public Category ParentCategory { get; private set; }       
   public ICollection<Category> SubCategories { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it, I added the following in the OnModelCreating operation:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Domain.Entities.Category>().HasOptional<Category>(c => c.ParentCategory).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey(new string[] { "Id", "ParentCategoryId" }));
```

and now the ParentCategory and SubCategories properties work (and I could remove Category1 and Category2). Don't know exactly why SubCategories works though...