# Many-to-many relationship between entities of same type in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application, where I use Entity Framework 4.3 Code-First and Migrations.

I've been trying to create a many-to-many relationship between entities of the same type, but when I scaffold the migration with Migrations, it generates a one-to-one relationship.

The idea is that one user should be able to follow multiple other users (think Twitter).

My `User` model look something like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Registered { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<User> Follows { get; set; }
}
```

When I scaffold the the added Follows-property, I get a migration like this:

```
public partial class FollowUser : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("User", "User_UserId", c => c.Int());
        AddForeignKey("User", "User_UserId", "User", "UserId");
        CreateIndex("User", "User_UserId");
    }

    ...
}
```

So Entity Framework interprets my model as a one-to-one relationship between two users.

**How can I create a many-to-many relationship between entities of the same type?**

Comment: @Blast_dan Thanks for your response! Not sure how that question relates to this though?

Comment: Woops wrong link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683716/mapping-for-self-referencing-entity-in-ef-code-first

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since It is a Many to Many Self Joined relationship, User entity should have a `Followers` and `Following` properties both of Type `User`. So Let us alter your class to include those

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public virtual ICollection<User> Followers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Following { get; set; }
}
```

Now update the DbContext class to have a Property which returns the Users

```
 public DbSet<User> Users { set; get; }
```

We need to tell EntityFramework that we need to have a many to many relations ship between these two. So Let us do that with Fluent API by overriding  `OnModelCreating` method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(m => m.Followers).WithMany(p => p.Following).Map(w => w.ToTable("User_Follow").MapLeftKey("UserId").MapRightKey("FollowerID"));
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Now Entity Framework will create the tables like this.

[image]

Note that we explicitly told Entity Framework to use **UserId** and **FollowerId** as the Forign Key column name. If we havent mentioned that, EF will use `User_ID` and `User_ID1` as the column names.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a really good answer, very clear. I'd +2 if I could.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson: Glad to know it helped you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would like to add some additional columns to User_Follower table. Is it possible to have this table as entity ?
Also i have noticed followers and followees are getting loaded eagerly, would it cause performance issues because i would prefer loading them lazily