# Lazy loading with EF 5 Database first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, lazy-loading, ef-database-first

I have three tables in my database:

- Post
- Author
- Tags

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 with EF 5 and my Post model (generated automatically) looks like this one:

```
public partial class BlogPost
{
    public BlogPost()
    {
        this.Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }

    ...

    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

My context and dbSet are definded. I'm trying to get all the posts in the database with this query

```
dbSet.ToList()
```

I thought that Author will be null and Tags will be empty, because I didn't use `Include()` to use eager loading. But if I debug, I found that Author isn't null and Tags got two elements. I don't understand why.

In Tag entity I got a navigation property to get all the posts that got that Tag. It looks like is filling all the data... but I don't notice any performance problem when I test the page, it load very fast.

Maybe it's not an error... am I just missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469432/entity-framework-code-first-lazy-loading):

> Lazy Loading means that entities will be automatically loaded when you
>   first access collection or navigation property, and that will happen
>   transparently, as though they were always loaded with parent object.
>
> Using "include" is loading on demand, when you specify properties you
>   want to query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I knew that I was missing something. :)