# EntityFramework adds duplicate related objects on SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, duplication

**Objects**

```
public class Noun
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Repository**

```
public Noun CreateNoun(string name, string categoryName)
{
    using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
    {
        Noun noun;
        Category category;

        lock (NounLock)
        {
            // don't create it if it already exists
            noun = context.Nouns
                .Include(t => t.Category)
                .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == name && t.Category.Name == categoryName);

            if (noun == null)
            {
                // make the category if it doesn't already exist
                lock (CategoryLock)
                {
                    category = context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == categoryName);
                    if (category == null)
                    {
                        category = new Category() { Name = categoryName };
                        context.Categories.Add(category);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }

                noun = new Noun()
                {
                    Name = name,
                    Category = category,
                    CategoryId = category.Id
                };

                context.Nouns.Add(noun);
            }
            else
            {
                category = noun.Category;
            }

            // make sure the noun is set as active
            noun.Active = true;

            context.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            context.SaveChanges();

            return noun;
        }
    }
}
```

**Context**

```
internal class MyContext : DbContext
{ 
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Noun> Nouns { get; set; }

    public MyContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Nouns
        modelBuilder.Entity<Noun>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.Category);
    }
}
```

**Question**

When calling CreateNoun(), when the noun with that category already exists, it should (based on what I think I am doing), just load the existing Noun from the db and mark it as active. But instead it inserts a new Noun, and a new Category. What am I doing wrong? I know it is probably a something small.

PS: The locks are static and in place because this is potentially used by a multi-threaded tenant

**Example**

```
Noun newNoun = repo.CreateNoun("name", "cat");
// should load existing noun from db, and set it as active, but instead duplicates it
Noun oldNoun = repo.CreateNoun("name", "cat");
```

Comment: Check to make sure your duplicate check is actually getting the duplicate.

Comment: try to remove context.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Unchanged to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I found the problem, and it was in another thread entirely that was duping by Noun's :( Multi threading is awesome. Thanks for all the comments/replies, upvotes for everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues in the `CreateNoun` method, I did some changes that I'm going to explain later:

```
public Noun CreateNoun(string name, string categoryName)
{
   using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
   {
       Noun noun;
       Category category;

       lock (NounLock)
       {
          // don't create it if it already exists
          noun = context.Nouns
                    .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == name && t.Category.Name == categoryName);

          if (noun == null)
          {
             // make the category if it doesn't already exist
             lock (CategoryLock)
             {
               category = context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == categoryName);
               if (category == null)
               {
                  category = new Category() { Name = categoryName };
                  context.Categories.Add(category);
                }
             }
             noun = new Noun()
             {
               Name = name,
               Category = category,
             };
             context.Nouns.Add(noun);
          }

          // make sure the noun is set as active
          noun.Active = true;

          context.SaveChanges();

          return noun;
       }
   }
}
```

- You don't need to call the `Include`, EF will load the Category
  property for you. This navegation property is virtual so, it will be
  [lazy loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469432/entity-framework-code-first-lazy-loading) .
- When you don't find the `Category`, you don't need to call the
  `SaveChanges` method. Before return the noum, you are calling this
  method, it will save all the changes that you did before.
- You don't need to set  the Foreign Key `CategoryId`. You don't know
  if the `category` was loaded from DB or recently created. Just set the
  navegation property `Category`.
- You don't need to change the `Category` State

Another Recomendation:

In the `OnModelCreating` method you are configuring `Category` as required. The method `HasRequired` is used when you want to configure a relationship. In your case it would be like this:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Noun>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.Category).WithMany().HasForeignKey(n=>n.CategoryId);
 }
```

### Update

As @Shoe said in his comment about the first point, If you want to use the `Noun` that is returned by this method and consult its Category, call the `Include` method when you search the `Noum` as you did before.

Comment: Your first bullet point isn't correct. Say he needed Category after his context was disposed. That will throw an exception without `Include`.

Comment: Hello @Shoe, you are right, I did not realize he could use the returned Noun outside, I thought he just want to insert or update those entities. I will update my answer.

Comment: Found the issue, but it was unrelated to anything I had shown, sorry about that. Have an upvote, and thanks for the tips, I incorporated them in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't marked your keys in the models. Both `Id` properties need to be marked with `[Key]` and the `Category` property in the `Noun` class requires a `[ForeignKey("CategoryId")]` annotation. As it stands the duplicate check is always failing because `t.Category.Name` is always null.

Comment: that is what model builder does. I actually looked at my DB and it has create primary/foreign keys without the decorations.