# Populating a Lazy<T> collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, collections, lazy-loading

I am trying to get my head around lazy loading in an ASP.Net MVC app. For instance, I have a class with a property that is a collection (Employees). I want the collection to only load when I need it loaded:

```
public class Department
{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")]
    public Lazy<ICollection<Employee>> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

First, I am not sure if I should lazy load the class or the collection

```
    public Lazy<ICollection<Employee>> Employees { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Lazy<Employee>> Employees { get; set; }
```

I assume the collection.

Next, I cannot seem to find a related example to actually load the property/collection once I need it and after the class has been instantiated. I am also not sure if this is done in the class itself or in my MVC controller.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are a *lot* of examples - when you *create* a new Lazy, you pass ghe factory method in its constructor. The factory will be called only when the Lazy's value is requested. Just declaring a `Lazy` property doesn't mean that anything will be evaluated lazily.

Comment: Is the Department class part of an EF model? In this case you don't need to declare the collection lazy

Comment: BTW did you mix up lazy loading (an ORM concept) with the unrelated concept of lazy evaluation (what `Lazy` is about)? *Relation* are lazily loaded by default - you *have* to use the `Include()` call to eagerly load related objects.

Comment: it is EF code-first. There are a lot of examples but I am probably unable to decipher them and apply them to my example.

Comment: It's possible I am mixing up concepts. Basically, if I set the employee collection as a virtual, I will get all the employees for each dept. when I call the class. That is only a good idea when I want to show all employees for one depart. On the other hand, when I have a dept dropdown on an employee view I don't want to load every employee for every depart when I instantiate this class. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the `Lazy<T>` on your `Employees` property. You'll just be adding unnecessary "lazyness", since Entity Framework (and other ORMs like NHibernate) queries are already lazy, i.e.: the query will only hit the database when you explicitly tell it to.

So, by making `Employees` of type:

`public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; } //make sure to mark it as virtual, otherwise it won't be lazy`

When querying:

`var result = myContextObj.Departments.Include(d=> d.Employees).Where(d=> d.Id == someID).SelectMany(d=> d.Employees);`

The code above does nothing but create a Query Object representing the query that may be sent to the database.But it's not going to do anything, unless you "materialize" the result, either by doing a `foreach` on `result`, or calling `ToList()` for example.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

For lazy loading you must:

- `public virtual ICollection<Lazy<Employee>> Employees { get; set; }`. You actually miss the `virtual` that allows the framework to create the proxy by overwritting the property;
- `context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;`, this is the defautl value.

Comment: Actually, when I reread this post I think I might understand what is happening:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469432/entity-framework-code-first-lazy-loading   When I had the property originally set as a virtual property (instead of Lazy<T>) and was debugging, I was actually accessing the property, thereby loading it. That threw me for a loop. So if I just set it back to "public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; } it should only load when the collection is accessed, right?