# Entity Framework Code first self referencing ID inserts wrong entity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble inserting into a table with code first using EF Core 2.0.

I get this exception when calling my `context.SaveChanges()`

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Departments' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Here is my Model:

```
public class Department 
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int? ParentDepartmentID { get; set; }
  public Department ParentDepartment { get; set; }
}
```

When I use the SQL Server Profiler I can see that the insert statement of an object which looks like this:
[image: Object im trying to save]

Is clearly trying to insert my ParentDepartment again.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Departments] ([ID], [Name], [ParentDepartmentID])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);
',N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(4000),@p2 int',@p0=1,@p1=N'Aalborg',@p2=NULL
```

My save function which saves the object shown above looks like this:

```
public string Save()
{
  string result = this.Validate();

  if (result.Equals(""))
  {
    using (LinerContext context = new LinerContext())
    {
      context.Departments.Add(this);
      context.SaveChanges();
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Really hope someone can help - thanks in advance!

Comment: From your screenshot it seems like your main object has an id set to (-2147482647). Do you initialize it to min value or something?

Comment: No I don't I guessed that's the default int value? , should I remove the setter on that property?

Comment: It seems that there is issue in the way you are saving data. Is the ID set to that large -ve number before you call `context.Departments.Add` on it?

Comment: Not sure, will follow up on it in the morning @smit

Comment: No, the ID is 0 before calling context.departments.Add()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed; I just needed to attach the parentdepartment to the dbset

Answer (score 0):

What you need is probably to change the way you have set your model. For self referencing you should probably do something like this (can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811194/what-is-the-syntax-for-self-referencing-foreign-keys-in-ef-code-first) for a Fluent API implementation on the model creation too):

```
public class Department 
{
    public int ID { get;set; }
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public int? ParentDeparmentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentDeparmentId ")]
    public Department ParentDeparment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that to no avail, exact same scenario. I cannot count the times I have dropped my DB and recreated with other migrations all different flavors of DataAnnotations and fluent API