# EF - How to define foreign key which is the primary key of the current table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have table name is Grades which have a column name Upgrade refer to value which is will be one of the values of the primary key in the table Grades - same table- 
I try to do this like the following code

```
public class Grades
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Grades UpGrade { get; set; }
        public int UpGradeId { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[ForeignKey]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#data-annotations) attribute should work just as well for self-referencing FKs as it works for regular [ForeignKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811194/what-is-the-syntax-for-self-referencing-foreign-keys-in-ef-code-first)

```
public class Grades
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UpGradeId")]
    public Grades UpGrade { get; set; }
    public int UpGradeId { get; set; }
}
```