# How to create a model with self reference in Entity Framework Code-First?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-3.0

I'm using Entity Framework Core 3.1 and trying to handle simple scenario: In sport league there a many games, but I want to handle postponed games. This is my model:

```
public class Game
{
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
    public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }
    public int? PostponedGameId { get; set; } // Original game that didn't happened and was postponed to 'this' game. 

    public Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
    public Game PostponedGame { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously for most games `PostponedGameId` will be null.

How can I create a `fluent API` that will generate nullable FK (PostponedGameId)?

**EDIT:**

This is what I have so far:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
            .HasOne<Game>(g => g.PostponedGame)
            .WithOne()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

But I don't know how to I state that `PostponedGameId` is foreign key. I'm not even sure if this is correct, because I didn't run it without specifying foreign key.

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#required-and-optional-relationships) help you?

Comment: @Twenty not exactly. In this post there is self reference, but "one to many". I need "one to one" self reference.

Comment: I am talking about the `.IsRequired()` method.

Comment: @Twenty I don't get it. It's not required. Most games are not postponed

Comment: The `IsRequired` method takes a boolean parameter which defines if the FK is required or not.

Comment: @Twenty I didn't even specify the FK. Look at my edit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the syntax for self referencing foreign keys in EF Code First?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811194/what-is-the-syntax-for-self-referencing-foreign-keys-in-ef-code-first)

Comment: @devNull There is `modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().HasOptional(c => c.Spouse).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.SpouseId);` why `WithMany`? I don't get it, because it's one-to-one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I would suggest something like the following:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
            .HasOne<Game>(g => g.PostponedGame)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Game>(g => g.PostponedGameId) // Defines the FK 
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .IsRequired(false); // Tells ef-core that the FK is optional
```

I am not able to verify the code at the moment, but it should work.